# Set window z-order above other

Tags: winapi

I'm making some type of invisible overlay window above another one. I know SetWindowPos but it only sets below of the other.

I need a way to keep updating the window position to keep exactly above, so if the window goes back the overlay goes together.
Making this overlay child of the other window doesn't help, 'cause the other window has some rendering stuff and the overlay window starts blinking.

Comment: The overlay window doesn't need to be a child of the other window, but the other window should [own the overlay window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows) so the overlay can't go behind the other window. You don't have to worry about managing z-order. Just intercept the other window's movements and reposition the overlay. If both windows are in the same process, use `SetWindowSubclass()` to handle `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`/`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` messages, otherwise use `SetWinEventHook()` to handle `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE` events.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Worked flawlessly! But I have to change the owner after window already created, so I'm using SetWindowLong(owned, GWL_HWNDPARENT, owner)

Comment: Just note that technically, `SetWindowLong(GWL_HWNDPARENT)` is not *officially* supported (it is not even documented), even if it "works". The only *official* way to set an owner is with the `hWndParent` parameter of `CreateWindow/Ex()`

Comment: Sure, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
SetWindowPos(window, GetNextWindow(below, GW_HWNDPREV), 0, 0, 0, 0,
             SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

to place a `window` above of `below`.